# How to specify color for mutliple lines in matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using the following matlab plot to draw multiple points

```
plot(ydep, xvar, '.', 'Markersize', 3);
```

Here ydep and xvar are matrix of 1024x300, so there will be 300 dotted lines being plotted in random color. What my question is how to specify the color for each of 300 lines in the parameter? I try to use a loop to plot each 'line' but that's pretty slow

```
for n=1:300
  plot(ydep(:, n), xvar(:, n), '.', 'Markersize', 3, 'color', linecolors(n, :));
  hold on;
end
```

where linecolors defined the color for each of the line.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have modified the code and I plot each individual 'line' in each iteration. By the way, I need to control the color myself since the random colors give the poor contrast and the figure is not accepted by the journal I submitted to.

Comment: yes, the problem is it is running too slow with my solution. If I run it only once, it is not that bad. But I have to run the code for thousand times  and also I need to tweak the parameter so to obtain the best figures (in some cases, I need even bigger matrix 5000x1000 for the lines). I just want to know if there is any way to make it run faster (as fast as that with one plot function). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the solution is to set the `ColorOrder`. Then you can just plot it as a matrix with matlabs regular high performance.

Here is an example of how to set the `ColorOrder`

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19815-explicitly-specifying-line-colors-when-plotting-a-matrix

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a more convenient way than messing with ColorOrder. The concept of the method is to get the handles of the plotted lines, and then to use the `set` command. Matlab provides colormaps which can be scaled to the size of your data set, which is very handy here.

I'll modify your example as follows:

```
h = plot(ydep, xvar, '.', 'Markersize', 3);
set(h,{'color'},num2cell(cool(length(h)),2));
```

This obtains the handles of all your dotted lines in the first code line. Then I used the colormap `cool` and scaled it to the same number as the number of elements in h. However, the colormap (which gives a regular matrix) cannot be used in the arguments of the `set` command directly. One way to specify multiple property values is to use cell arrays, so that's what this example does.

All credit goes to Kelly Kearney for her answer on [Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19815-explicitly-specifying-line-colors-when-plotting-a-matrix).